# Can't copy PPA package to another series: "same version already building"

Tags: ppa, launchpad

I have a PPA with a package built for Precise, which I want to also have available for Trusty. I've read that is as simple as using the "copy packages" feature in Launchpad. When I do so, I get the message:

```
Copying failed of <package> (<version>)   Remove notification
Copied from: <ppa name>. Target series: Trusty
<package> <version> in precise (same version already building in the destination archive for Precise)
```

it sounds like it failed to copy to "Trust" because it is already in "Precise" - which seems stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not that simple.

There's a requirement that there cannot be the same version of a package but with different contents in a given archive. What this means is that you can't tell Launchpad to rebuild a package for Trusty when it's built for Precise (in your own PPA), because the version is the same, but the final deb packages will be different (your entire PPA is considered one archive). This is more of a limitation of the Debian/Ubuntu repo format than anything else.

You can either copy the binaries as is (which I personally don't recommend, due to the large difference in library versions) or upload the package with different version numbers for each release. Appending something like `~trusty1` will work. See [my PPA](https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/flightgear-edge) for an example.

Comment: Why not create a packaging recipe?

Comment: You could also do that if the sources are available in Launchpad's Code Hosting.

Comment: Bummer. I personally find RPM and yum, with all their deficiencies, to still be much friendlier to packagers then the hugely complex and problematic deb/apt system.